# Variable verification to output a message

Tags: python

So, I have 3 variables the total of which should be 120. I have done the verification of that. The variables should be equal to 0 or 20 or 40 or 60 or 80 or 100 or 120. I have done the verification for that as well but now what I need is for my program to check if variable 1 is 100 and variable 2 is 0 or 20 and variable 3 is 0 or 20 in terms to output a message. Then I need to check if variable 1 is 40 or 60 or 80 variable 2 is 0 or 20 or 40 or 60 or 80 and variable 3 is 0 or 20 or 40 or 60 in terms to output a different message.

```
if pass_credit + defer_credit + fail_credit != 120:
    print("Total incorrect!")
elif pass_credit == 120 and defer_credit == 0 fail_credit == 0:
    print("Progress")
    break
elif pass_credit == 100 and defer_credit == 0 or 20 and fail_credit == 0 or 20:
    print("Progress - module trailer")
    break
```

That's what I have so far

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58833394/edit) button.

Comment: `break` is used to exit a `loop`. Since you don't have a `loop`, don't use it.

Comment: I do have a loop and I need it to exit the loop if any of the conditions are met. This is just a part of my code

Comment: [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/1324033) - You still haven't said what it is you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the semantics of this line is wrong:

```
elif pass_credit == 100 and defer_credit == 0 or 20 and fail_credit == 0 or 20:
```

Either write

```
elif pass_credit == 100 and (defer_credit == 0 or defer_credit == 20) and (fail_credit == 0 or fail_credit == 20):
```

or write

```
elif pass_credit == 100 and defer_credit in (0, 20) and fail_credit in (0, 20):
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a general message for all the good combinations (with the values), use:

```
a, b, c = 80, 40, 0
message = "The values are: "
for i, var in enumerate([a, b, c]):
    message += "Variable " + str(i + 1) + " is: " + str(var) + ", "
print(message[:-2] if a + b + c == 120 else "Total incorrect!")
```

Output:

```
The values are: Variable 1 is: 80, Variable 2 is: 40, Variable 3 is: 0
```

If you want a different message for every possible combination, continue your `elif`s to cover all options (with @gelonida's correction for the syntex). No smart way to do that.